# Issue with changing notepad icon on Winows 7

Tags: windows-7, icons

I installed a program (Subtitle Edit) and it changed my .srt icon. Now I can't seem to change it back (I use FileTypesMan for this) since I can't find where the icon is stored even though several other extensions are still using it.

Here you can see the icons in FileTypesMan. I want .srt files to use the .sub icon.

[image]

Is this icon located somewhere on Windows 7? notepad.exe only seems to have one icon in it (the one used for .srt above) and I don't remember how I initially set the one I have for .sub and when I double-click on .sub in FileTypesMan I don't get any icon directory path.

I already checked a long list of .dll's listed in another question, but I couldn't find it there.

<sub>I managed to solve it myself by deleting everything from the "Default Icon", "MIME Type" and "Perceived Type" text boxes under Edit File Type in FileTypesMan.</sub>

Comment: Post your own solution as an answer down below, please, in order to help others. Answers don't go in questions.

Answer (score 1):

Delete everything from the *Default Icon*, *MIME Type* and *Perceived Type* text boxes under *Edit File Type* in *FileTypesMan*.